# How to use MySQLi Driver in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

How can I use mysqli drivers in PHP native query?

For example. My code:

Model

```
class Home_model extends CI_Model{
    public function getusers(){
        $q = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
        return $r = mysqli_query($q);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{
    public function iterateuser(){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($this->Home_model->getusers())) {
            echo $row->username;
        }
    }
```

My code above has an error, saying:

> mysqli_query expects at least 2 parameters

Is there a way in CodeIgniter to pass the link on the `mysqli_query()` first parameter as described on the php.net documentation http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 16):

go to:

```
yourproject/application/config/database.php
```

change:

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

with:

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

Answer (score 3):

You should change the content of the file `DB_driver.php` in you codeigniter system directory. Go to:

```
system/database/DB_driver.php
```

And change the following line:

```
var $dbdriver = 'mysql';
```

to :

```
var $dbdriver = 'mysqli';
```

here is a extraction of the `DB_driver.php`

```
 * MySQLi Database Adapter Class - MySQLi only works with PHP 5
 *
 * Note: _DB is an extender class that the app controller
 * creates dynamically based on whether the active record
 * class is being used or not.
 *
 * @package        CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage    Drivers
 * @category    Database
 * @author        ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @link        http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/
 */
class CI_DB_mysqli_driver extends CI_DB {

    var $dbdriver = 'mysqli';
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you have specified `'mysqli'`,
you can use the following function to get mysqli. For example, `mysqli_real_escape_str`, etc.:

```
function get_mysqli() { 
    $db = (array)get_instance()->db;
    return mysqli_connect('localhost', $db['username'], $db['password'], $db['database']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the file '**database.php**' under the folder '**/application/config/**'

Move to the line

```
$db['default'] = array('dbdriver' => '')
```

Modify it as below

```
$db['default'] = array('dbdriver' => 'mysqli')
```