# Blank page loading in xampp codeigniter project

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I was working on codeigniter  using ammps. But I migrated to xampp. When I did that the project loads only a blank page. no error messages nothing.

In application\database\config\database file, When I change  `$db['default']['dbdriver] = mysql` to `$db['default']['dbdriver] = mysqli` loads the project but when login to the system shows many sql errors.

please help me to find a solution for this.

Comment: Check out this question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093825/how-to-use-mysqli-driver-in-codeigniter

Comment: there is single quote missing too i.e. $db['default']['dbdriver] should like $db['default']['dbdriver']

Comment: What version of codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

update database.php file  with below setting

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE; // enable database error
```

and  in config.php enable error logging

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

check application/logs/'today's log file'

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the environment constant in the **index.php** file

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

I think by seeing the error you can check what's going wrong.